# How to handle current bar minutes that add up to over 60 minutes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a script that captures values at specific but varying bar times after a market opens. Market open and subsequent capture time is specified via menu input. For example:

```
hr_open      = input.int(defval= 9, title='Hour')         // input opening time, hr of day
min_open     = input.int(defval= 30,title='Min')          // input opening time, min of day
min_added    = input.int(defval= 30)                      // input minutes past open

// define capture  time
capture_time = (hour == hr_open) and (minute == min_open + min_added) time

// capture X,Y,Z at capture_time                  
if capture_time                                           
    // .....capture value of X, Y, Z
```

To illustrate the problem, lets assume the user inputs an opening time of 9 hours and 30 minutes. The user inputs 15 minutes after open as the time to take action. The script adds min_open + min_added = 30 + 15 = 45. Action takes place at 9:45. Everything works as expected.

But if min_added is 35, the script adds = 30 + 35 and tries to take action at 9:65. The script fails for obvious reasons. Is there any elegant work around that allows the script to "convert" 9:65 AM to 10:05 AM

Answer (score 1):

For time manipulation, you can use [timestamp()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_timestamp). This function generates a proper date passing positive or negative offsets in arguments, in your case `min_added`:

```
// define capture  time
capture_time = time == timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, hr_open, min_open + min_added)
```